# Transferring files from remote host to local with sshpass

Tags: bash, shell-script, scp

I want to transfer files which are older then 40 days from remote to local host.
I am able to connect the remote server but unable to transfer the files from remote to local server.
It results into error which says no files No such file or directory but the file exists on the remote hosts.

## Details:

```
file=`sshpass -p "password" ssh username@server_ip "find /arch -type f -ctime -40"`
sshpass -p "password" scp -r  username@server_ip:$file /arch
echo SCP Completed.
```

## Error details:

```
cp: cannot stat ‘/arch/file1.xls’: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Does the error message actually say `cp` and not `scp`?

Comment: did `time yourscript` work to capture start and end time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take care of one thing or two:

- Permissions: You might not have the right permissions to read a file;
- Multiline answer: Your find could give you more than one file as result.

Long story short, probably your problem is not `sshpass`.

From now, we take for granted that you do not have issues related to permissions.

What you can do is something like that:

```
files="$(sshpass -p "passwd" ssh -l username rhost "find /arch -type f -ctime -40")"
for file in ${files}; do
  if sshpass -p "passwd" scp "username@rhost:${file}" /arch; then
    printf "SCP Completed\n"
  fi
done
```

Theoretically, `$files` will not contain what you can't grab, because `find` will print in `stderr` the files (folders) that you cannot reach, so you should manage that in a separate way.

Among all the options, you can merge `stderr` with `stdout` and add a condition in your `for` cycle or save the errors in another var (or file) and cycle them separately.

Comment: The for loop errors out as mentioned below and unable to copy the file from remote server.

Error details:
usage: scp [-12346BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
           [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program]
           [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I mistakenly used a `-l username` in scp

Comment: Thanks ingroxd it worked, can we include the timings as well so that i can capture the start time and end time?.

Comment: You can just type `time yourscript`